# Indecomposable and width representations of a poset

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

I would like some help to be able to prove the following theorem about posets:

"Let $ P $ be a poset with width less than two, then all its indecomposable representations are trivial"

I have been thinking about it for several days but I have not had much luck, I would also like to know if it is possible to find this exercise in a page or book.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: how are you defining a representation of a poset?

Comment: ...a functor $P \to Set$?